# Numpy / Pandas: randomly choose n items from a list, for where n is a random integer, for each index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, random, series

I am new with numpy and pandas, and I am trying to write this piece of code which creates a pandas Series. For every index in the Series I want to randomly choose a random number of interests, 1 - 3 in this case with no duplicates, from the list above. I would like to find ways to improve my code if possible.

Thanks

```
def random_interests(num):
    interests = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    stu_interests = []
    for n in range(num):
        stu_interests.append(np.random.choice(interests, np.random.randint(1, 4), replace=False))
    rand_interests = pd.Series(stu_interests)
```

Comment: Does your solution work? If not how is it deficient?

Comment: It does work, but I'm just trying to learn ways to improve it since I'm new to numpy / pandas

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is working code and OP is looking for alternatives. Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: If your solution does work, take the [CodeReview Tour](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit its [Help Center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking) to see if your question is on topic over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it. For loop can be avoided by using apply which is faster. Also, you need not create a separate variable `stu_interests` which can consume more memory when `num` is high

```
def random_interests(num):
    interests = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    rand_interests = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=[x for x in range(num)], columns=['random_list'])
    rand_interests['random_list'] =  rand_interests['random_list'].apply(lambda x: np.random.choice(interests, np.random.randint(1, 4), replace=False))
    return rand_interests['random_list']
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add a return to your function, so that you will get a result from it. By adding a return at the bottom, your code will be:

```
def random_interests(num):
    interests = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    stu_interests = []
    for n in range(num):
        stu_interests.append(np.random.choice(interests, np.random.randint(1, 4), replace=False))
    rand_interests = pd.Series(stu_interests)
    return rand_interests
```

And by running it for n=5 output is:

```
random_interests(5)

0    [5, 6, 4]
1          [5]
2    [1, 6, 4]
3    [3, 4, 1]
4       [1, 2]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks! I omitted the last return to keep things shorter, so you believe that the code is good as it is?

Comment: Yes it's perfect

Answer (score 0):

Or the one liner

```
pd.Series([np.random.choice(
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], np.random.randint(1, 4), replace=False)
           for i in range(num)])
```

Output:

```
0       [3, 6]
1    [4, 2, 1]
2       [6, 5]
3          [3]
```

Comment: Good.. I appreciate the wow factor of a single line. However, do you think storing a list [1, 2,3, 4, 5, 6] in a variable would be better since it is getting reused?

Comment: yes, if you are reusing `[1, 2,3, 4, 5, 6]` then better to store it  in a variable and use the same variable in single liner (just like  variable num)